# Earthquake intensity overlay in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kmz

I downloaded an earthquake shake map for USGS with KMZ file.

It is appears in Google Earth as below.

[image: Intensity over lay]

I would like to use this intensity in ArcMap. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the content of the KMZ/KML file, is it a link to a WMS or other image, is it some vector data?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason ArcMap doesn't like the intensity overlay. I tried and got an error saying they were empty features. I was able to get the intensity polygons to load using the [`KMLtoLayer`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-to-layer.htm) tool.

[image]

[image]